# Modelica libraries use different MSL version

Tags: annotations, version, modelica, dymola

I want to use two Modelica libraries together, in Dymola, so for convenience I wrote a little script, `loadLibraries.mos` that just opens the two libraries. 
But they use different versions of the MSL (3.2.1 versus 3.2.2), defined by the uses annotation in the top level package.mo:

```
annotation(uses(Modelica(version="3.2.1")));
```

The library developed by us uses 3.2.2, the library that uses MSL 3.2.1 is developed by someone else.
Now whenever I run the mos script (or when I open the two libraries manually), Dymola wants to run an update script. As far as I can see, nothing gets changed by the update script, so I would like to

- either not run it at all, e.g. by defining a range of accepted versions like `annotation(uses(Modelica(version>="3.2.1")));`
- or always run it, without asking first, e.g. by setting some flag `AlwaysSilentyAcceptMSLUpgrade`.
  Under Edit, Options, Version there is a checkmark `Force upgrade of models to MSL version` but I am unsure how to use it from my mos script (for all users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change your own library, but make the library using Modelica 3.2.1 read-only (e.g. by making the files read-only).

That should skip the prompt (at least from Dymola 2016) - and as far as I understand you don't edit that library yourself anyway.

That works for libraries that don't need any update between the versions; which obviously holds for Modelica 3.2.1->3.2.2 since there is no conversion - but it would also work if there were a conversion that didn't influence this particular library.

Answer (score 3):

My pragmatic solution would be to ask yourself if your own library **really** needs anything from 3.2.2 which is not yet present in 3.2.1. Hence change your library to only require 3.2.1. Or the other way round (given you can change the `package.mo` of the other library) change the `uses` annotation there to 3.2.2

Comment: Ah and yes in an ideal world the [MCP-0016](https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/1728) would have already been implemented ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I marked Hans' answer as solution, because it will also work (for me) if the libraries cannot be changed to use the sam eMSL version.

Comment: Sure, no problem.